# understanding asyncio await behaviour

Tags: python-asyncio

I have the following example code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import asyncio

async def h():
    print("h() has started")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("h() has ended")

async def main():
    print("{}: start of program".format(datetime.now()))
    await h()
    print("{}: end of program".format(datetime.now()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I would have expected (and would like the output of code) to be something along the following lines:

```
2020-03-03 17:31:25.379742: start of program
h() has started
2020-03-03 17:31:30.384977: end of program
h() has ended
```

however I have the following output:

```
2020-03-03 17:31:25.379742: start of program
h() has started
h() has ended
2020-03-03 17:31:30.384977: end of program
```

Is there a specific reason as to why this is happening and how I can go about achieving the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of **awaiting** a coroutine such as `h()` is to **wait** for it to complete, and (where that makes sense) access its return value. For example, `line = await stream.readline()` suspends the current coroutine until `readline()` finishes, and then provides the result to assign to `line`.

If you want `h()` to run in the background, you can use [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) instead. But it still won't result in the desired output, because `run_until_complete(main())` only waits for `main()` to finish, disregarding additional tasks it may have spawned. (It also returns the return value of the coroutine, much like a sync equivalent of `await`.)

If you want to wait for additional tasks, you have to be explicit about it. Perhaps something like:

```py
async def main():
    bgtasks = []
    print("{}: start of program".format(datetime.now()))
    bgtasks.append(asyncio.create_task(h()))
    print("{}: end of program".format(datetime.now()))
    return bgtasks

async def run_everything():
    more_tasks = await main()
    await asyncio.gather(*more_tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(run_everything())
```

Comment: @Nilzy123 You're welcome! And if the issue is now resolved, feel free to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/627709).